# How do I obtain token used to enable ubuntu-advantage esm?

Tags: 12.04, security, aws, ubuntu-advantage, esm

Per the instructions in https://www.ubuntu.com/support/esm, I should be able to enable esm by running `sudo ubuntu-advantage enable-esm [ENTER TOKEN]`.  I've purchased "Ubuntu Advantage - Essentials" through the AWS Marketplace, but it is unclear to me where I get the token.

Also, I do not want to manage through Landscape.

Comment: I think you probably need to ask Canonical support, which you're now paying for, that question.

Answer (score 0):

@dobey is correct. Please get in touch with Canonical support via ticketing system https://support.canonical.com  or phone and they will help with enabling ESM service.